# How does a 'corrected probability' work when there is sampling of minority and majority classes?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

I have a dataset that has the following 0's and 1's:

```
  0     1 
73012  3008
```

A corrected Probability is being used to lower it to:

```
3,600 (0's) and 1,200 (1's)
```

The following formula is given:

```
correctedProbability=1/(1+((1/populationproportion)-1)/((1/sampleproportion)-1)*((1/predictedprobability)-1))
```

Someone with enough statistics, how are they coming up with the number of selected 0's and 1's?